# Mysql table already exists, can't drop database, can access the invisible table

Tags: mysql

When I try to access it:
[image: When I try to access it]

But check this out:
[image: But check this out]

I'm pretty sure that it is because I delete the databases without dropping it first. Can any one help me?

Comment: what version of mysql you're using?

Comment: Have you issued a `DROP DATABASE db_name`? if so make sure any files in your `mysql\data\Ascii` folder are deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that maybe information schema doesn't have the proper data? (or does)

Try running the following, and it should give you your answer:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
       FROM information_schema.TABLES
       WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Ascii';
```

`SHOW TABLES` most likely uses the file structure.

If you run this query:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';
 +---------------+-----------------------+
 | Variable_name | Value                 |
 +---------------+-----------------------+
 | datadir       | /usr/local/mysql/var/ |
 +---------------+-----------------------+
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then do `ls /usr/local/mysql/var/Ascii/`, you should be able to see the table files. There should be an .frm, .MYD, and .MYI

Comment: Hey Thanks, I just delete the whole mysql.

Comment: _(:з」∠)_ It took me about 40 mins to import the data and run it LOL.

Comment: @VinJERHero,if this answer works for you, you can click accept button (the green tick under the voting arrows in the top left corner of this answer)